отвечает только на первые ответы в чате
У меня возникла проблема: я хочу отвечать на все ответы к комментарию, но отвечает только на первый уровень ответов (то есть на ответы к основному комментарию) и на те ответы, которые относятся именно к этому комментарию. На остальные ответы (второго или третьего уровня) не появляется ответ. Как это исправить?
const getTimeAgo = (date) => {
        const now = new Date();
        const seconds = Math.floor((now - date) / 1000);

        if (seconds < 60) {
            return `${seconds} сек тому`;
        } else if (seconds < 3600) {
            const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            return `${minutes} хв тому`;
        } else if (seconds < 86400) {
            const hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
            return `${hours} год тому`;
        } else {
            const days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
            return `${days} дн. тому`;
        }
    };

    let repliesVisibilityMap = {}; // Об'єкт для збереження стану видимості відповідей

    const loadComments = async () => {
        const commentsMap = {};

        const commentsSnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "comments"), orderBy("createdAt", "asc")));
        commentsList.innerHTML = ''; // Очищаємо список перед відображенням нових коментарів

        commentsSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const commentData = doc.data();
            commentData.id = doc.id;

            // Якщо це відповідь, додаємо ім'я автора, кому відповідають
            if (commentData.parentCommentId) {
                const parentComment = commentsSnapshot.docs.find((parentDoc) => parentDoc.id === commentData.parentCommentId);
                if (parentComment) {
                    commentData.parentAuthorName = parentComment.data().name;
                }
            }

            if (commentData.postId === postId) {
                if (commentData.parentCommentId) {
                    if (!commentsMap[commentData.parentCommentId]) {
                        commentsMap[commentData.parentCommentId] = [];
                    }
                    commentsMap[commentData.parentCommentId].push(commentData);
                } else {
                    if (!commentsMap[null]) {
                        commentsMap[null] = [];
                    }
                    commentsMap[null].push(commentData);
                }
            }
        });


        if (commentsMap[null]) {
            commentsMap[null].forEach((comment) => {
                const commentElement = createCommentElement(comment.id, comment, 0);
                commentsList.appendChild(commentElement);

                if (commentsMap[comment.id]) {
                    const repliesContainer = document.createElement('div');
                    const repliesAreVisible = repliesVisibilityMap[comment.id] || false;
                    repliesContainer.style.display = repliesAreVisible ? 'block' : 'none';

                    commentsMap[comment.id].forEach((reply) => {
                        const replyElement = createCommentElement(reply.id, reply, 1);
                        repliesContainer.appendChild(replyElement);

                        if (commentsMap[reply.id]) {
                            commentsMap[reply.id].forEach((subReply) => {
                                const subReplyElement = createCommentElement(subReply.id, subReply, 2);
                                repliesContainer.appendChild(subReplyElement);
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    const showRepliesButton = document.createElement('button');
                    showRepliesButton.textContent = repliesAreVisible ? 'Приховати відповіді' : 'Всі відповіді';
                    showRepliesButton.style.marginLeft = "10px";
                    showRepliesButton.style.marginBottom = "10px";
                    showRepliesButton.classList.add("show-replies-btn");
                    showRepliesButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        repliesVisibilityMap[comment.id] = !repliesVisibilityMap[comment.id];
                        repliesContainer.style.display = repliesVisibilityMap[comment.id] ? 'block' : 'none';
                        showRepliesButton.textContent = repliesVisibilityMap[comment.id] ? 'Приховати відповіді' : 'Всі відповіді';
                    });

                    commentElement.appendChild(showRepliesButton);
                    commentElement.appendChild(repliesContainer);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    const createCommentElement = (commentId, commentData, level = 0) => {
        const commentElement = document.createElement('div');
        commentElement.classList.add('comment');
        commentElement.style.borderBottom = '1px solid #ddd';
        commentElement.style.padding = '10px';
        commentElement.style.marginBottom = '10px';
        commentElement.style.position = 'relative';

        // Ім'я автора
        const nameElement = document.createElement('p');
        nameElement.textContent = commentData.name;
        nameElement.style.color = 'black';
        nameElement.style.fontSize = '16px';
        nameElement.style.fontWeight = 'bold';

        // Текст коментаря
        const commentContent = document.createElement('p');
        commentContent.textContent = commentData.comment;

        // Час створення
        const createdAt = commentData.createdAt.seconds
            ? new Date(commentData.createdAt.seconds * 1000)
            : new Date();
        const timeAgo = getTimeAgo(createdAt);

        const dateElement = document.createElement('small');
        dateElement.textContent = timeAgo;
        dateElement.style.color = 'gray';
        dateElement.style.fontSize = '12px';
        dateElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        dateElement.style.top = '10px';
        dateElement.style.right = '10px';

        // Адресат відповіді (якщо є)
        if (commentData.replyTo) {
            const replyToElement = document.createElement('small');
            replyToElement.textContent = `До: ${commentData.replyTo}`;
            replyToElement.style.color = 'gray';
            replyToElement.style.fontSize = '12px';
            replyToElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            replyToElement.style.bottom = '10px';
            replyToElement.style.right = '10px';
            commentElement.appendChild(replyToElement);
        }

        // Кнопка "Відповісти"
        const replyButton = document.createElement('button');
        replyButton.textContent = 'Відповісти';
        replyButton.classList.add('reply-button');
        replyButton.style.marginTop = '10px';

        replyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const existingForm = document.getElementById(`replyForm-${commentId}`);
            if (!existingForm) {
                const replyForm = createReplyForm(commentId, commentData.name);
                commentElement.appendChild(replyForm);
            }
        });

        commentElement.appendChild(nameElement);
        commentElement.appendChild(commentContent);
        commentElement.appendChild(dateElement);
        commentElement.appendChild(replyButton);

        return commentElement;
    };

    const createReplyForm = (parentCommentId, parentAuthorName) => {
        const replyForm = document.createElement('form');
        replyForm.style.marginTop = '10px';
        replyForm.id = `replyForm-${parentCommentId}`;

        const replyText = document.createElement('textarea');
        replyText.placeholder = `Ваш коментар до ${parentAuthorName}...`;
        replyText.style.width = '100%';
        replyText.style.height = '50px';
        replyText.classList.add("areatext-reply");
        replyForm.appendChild(replyText);

        const replySubmit = document.createElement('button');
        replySubmit.textContent = 'Відправити';
        replySubmit.classList.add('reply-submit');
        replySubmit.style.marginTop = '5px';
        replyForm.appendChild(replySubmit);

        const cancelButton = document.createElement('button');
        cancelButton.textContent = 'Скасувати';
        cancelButton.style.marginLeft = '10px';
        cancelButton.style.marginTop = '5px';
        cancelButton.classList.add('reply-cancel');
        replyForm.appendChild(cancelButton);

        replyForm.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const replyComment = replyText.value;
            if (replyComment) {
                const user = auth.currentUser;
                if (user) {
                    const nickname = await getUserNickname(user.uid);
                    await addDoc(collection(db, "comments"), {
                        postId: postId,
                        comment: replyComment,
                        name: nickname,
                        userId: user.uid,
                        createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
                        parentCommentId: parentCommentId,
                        parentAuthorName: parentAuthorName
                    });
                    replyText.value = '';
                    loadComments();
                } else {
                    alert('Сначала ввойдите!');
                }
            }
        });

        cancelButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            replyForm.remove();
        });

        return replyForm;
    };


    const getUserNickname = async (userId) => {
        try {
            const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", userId);
            const userDoc = await getDoc(userDocRef);

            if (userDoc.exists()) {
                return userDoc.data().name || 'Anonim';
            } else {
                return 'Anonim';
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
            return 'Anonim';
        }
    };


    window.onload = () => {
        loadPost();
        loadComments();
    };


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.
